# SQL select top five most recent row and distinct by a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, So say I have a table as picture below name appModelFlat only with a few hundred more rows. It does not have a date field but I want to find out the five most recently created environments (EnvName). There is only 14 possible environments (EnvName). But I want to select the five most recently inserted rows that inserted different EnvName. That is to say I want to select distinct EnvName (Although distinct doesn't work this way) most recent 5 rows , and I know they are the most recent by their id. The higher the id the newer the row is. Any help on this query would be appreciated.

```
id|AppName|EnvName|ServerTypeName|ServerId|OS     |OSVersion|CPU|Memory|ExtraStorage|MachineDesc   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 |ASB    |DEV    |App           |1       |Windows|7        |4  |4     |100         |ASB-DEV-App   |

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5 |AMS    |DEV    |APP           |2       |RedHat |7.2      |4  |4     |50          |AMS-DEV-App   |

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6 |SPB    |TST    |App           |1       |Windows|7        |2  |8     |50          |SPB-TST-App   |

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7 |SBI    |TST    |Oracle        |1       |Solaris|11       |4  |8     |100         |SBI-TST-Oracle|

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my first attempt although I'm not sure if it is right. It does give me five results.

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT top 5  [ID] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [ID]  FROM [AppModelFlat] Y WHERE Y.[EnvName] = X.[EnvName])
            ,[AppName]= ( SELECT TOP 1 [AppName] FROM [AppModelFlat] Y WHERE Y.[EnvName] = X.[EnvName])
            ,[EnvName] 
            ,[ServerTypeName] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [ServerTypeName] FROM [AppModelFlat] Y WHERE Y.[EnvName] = X.[EnvName])
            ,[ServerId] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [ServerId] FROM [AppModelFlat] Y WHERE Y.[EnvName] = X.[EnvName])
            ,[OS] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [OS] FROM [AppModelFlat] Y WHERE Y.[EnvName] = X.[EnvName])
        FROM [AppModelFlat] X order by id desc
```

edit:

For expected result. Lets say I only wanted to select the top 2 since I only gave 5 entries here. I would want to get back the following.

```
5 |AMS    |DEV    |APP           |2       |RedHat |7.2      |4  |4     |50          |AMS-DEV-App   |

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7 |SBI    |TST    |Oracle        |1       |Solaris|11       |4  |8     |100         |SBI-TST-Oracle|
```

Because I only have one of each EnvName and each row has the highest Id number for that row.

Comment: I hope I'm not being rude but, I literally did exactly that except for expected result. Did you even read the questions

Comment: i saw the sample data,but showing expected result helps a lot ,instead of explaining in words.

Comment: also  try seeing the link referenced to know on , how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: The wording i have `please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text` is a  generic one ,which i use  for lot of questions that don't have both.In this case only expected results applies to you

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the latest row for each `EnvName`, and only taking the `top 5` from ordered `Id desc`

```
select top 5 *
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by EnvName order by id desc)
  from appModelFlat 
  ) s
where rn = 1
order by id desc
```

[**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) version:

```
select top 5 *
from (
  select top 1 with ties *
  from appModelFlat
  order by row_number() over (partition by EnvName order by id desc)
  ) s
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple sub query would also do the trick:

```
SELECT      TOP 5 Id, AppName, EnvName, ServerTypeName, ServerId, OS
FROM        AppModelFlat Records
INNER JOIN  (SELECT EnvName,
                    MAX(Id) as Id
             FROM   AppModelFlat) Latest ON Records.Id = Latest.Id
```

Comment: sorry, missed the GROUP BY EnvName in the subquery.